# Flutter pick video from local storage

Tags: flutter, file, video

I am working with flutter.
I am trying to make users pick videos from their local storage.
Can anyone tell me how I can do this please?
+
Also, I want to show a thumbnail image of that video when the video is picked.
Anyone know how to do this?
Please help me out guys thanks

Comment: You could use a plugin named `file_picker` to make the user select a file from his device files system

Answer (score 0):

use image_picker package, [link](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

```
VideoPlayerController? _controller;
  getVideo() async {
    try {
      XFile? video = await ImagePicker().pickVideo(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
      );
      if (video != null) {
        setState(() {
          _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(video.path))
            ..initialize();
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

for thumbnail,

```
if (_controller != null)
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    child: SizedBox(
                        height: 75,
                        width: 75,
                        child: VideoPlayer(_controller!)),
                  ),
```